# Inspect Traffic Destined for Another Local Application

Tags: .net, tcp, network-programming, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am writing a tool to automate a much older tool that our company uses. It uses its own console-like system where the entire thing is controlled via text. I have already written parts of a program that will detect the window handle, send keystrokes to it, and even OCR the screen shot to determine what is on the screen. However, the OCR isn't perfect, and it occurred to me that the characters are going to be sent via TCP/IP anyway, so why not just read the stream and then I'll know what the program is displaying to the user without relying on OCR. However, I have no clue how to do this. Does anyone have any suggestions for this challenge?

The program I'm writing is in VB.Net 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pcap.net which is a wrapper for WinPCap [PCap.net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/)

I wish you good luck for the OCR part, never is a reliable thing, unless you add post processing, which I can only recommend !

Comment: Actually the OCR part is working pretty well (with plenty of post-processing), but I figured packet inspection would be even better. I was hoping there was some facility to just ask a library what data is program x receiving from interface y and then I could get a copy of it.

Comment: Hum, no I dont have knowledge of such an easy way. But using PcapNet isnt too hard. A bit weird at the start if you arent used to working with buffers and stuff like that, but it really does work pretty well, and allows you to do some nice stuff quite easily. Plus it is quite performant.

Edit : you will probably have to go quite deep into Win32 to get some information about the networking, but you will still need a lib to capture correctly the data.

Comment: thanks for your help. Given the effort that's required I'm not sure if it is worth it (I'm over 95% accurate on the OCR). However, I'll keep it in mind. I'm sure that others could use a tool like this. I'm kind of surprised there isn't one.